# How can i upload files on dropzone.js with style="display: none;" using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dropzone.js

I'm trying to upload files on a website which using dropzone.js for file uploads.
I've found the file upload field in form, but the script stops without throwing any error.
I've also used find_elements_by_id("upload-input") to make sure there are not multiple fields with same id.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("upload-input")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
elem.send_keys("C:\KVR.pdf")
```

This is how html looks like:

```
 <div id="fallback" style="display: none;">
    <input id="upload-input" type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple">
    <div id="upload-progress" class="upload-progress"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the error stack trace you are observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the `<input>` tag is having *style* set to **display: none;**. You can use the following code block to upload the file :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='fallback']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='upload-input']").send_keys("C:\\KVR.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

DropzoneJS hides the `<input type="file">`
You can find those with the instruction below:

```
 dz_inputs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file' and @class='dz-hidden-input']")
```

Then for example, to add a file to the first dropzone on the page, you should proceed as below:

```
dz_inputs[0].send_keys("/File/path/file_name.extension")
```