# How can make (style ="display: none;") element visible in HTML in python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to upload file using python selenium on a website whose file field in html looks like this:

```
 <div id="fallback" style="display: none;">
    <input id="upload-input" type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple">
    <div id="upload-progress" class="upload-progress"></div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to make element visible via following code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='upload-input']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", elem)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='upload-input']")
```

After running the script, script stops without uploading the file and without throwing any error.

After using elem.is_displayed(), I've found the element is still not displayed even after running the above block of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i upload files on dropzone.js with style="display: none;" using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144538/how-can-i-upload-files-on-dropzone-js-with-style-display-none-using-selenium)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `style` attribute is on the wrapping `<div>`, but you're trying to remove it from the `<input>`:

```py
container = driver.find_element_by_id("fallback")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", container)

input = driver.find_element_by_id("upload-input")
input.send_keys(path_to_file)
```

**P.S.** The use of the `style` attribute is an implementation detail of *how* an element is styled. In this case, you really only care about *what* the style is, so better to specifically *set* it to what you want rather than *delete* a particular way of *implementing* it. The former should be less brittle.

**P.P.S.** You probably don't need to use XPath for something as simple as a lookup by ID. (IDs should be unique across all elements; otherwise they're not really IDs.)