# Click a button to display a text box in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click a button which un-hides another text box. The button click changes the script from

```
<span id="incident.u_brand_edit" style="display: none;">
```

to

```
<span id="incident.u_brand_edit" style>
```

Following is the button HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-ref" type="button" aria-labelledby="incident.u_brand_title_text" 
data-target="#incident\.u_brand" title="" tabindex="0" id="incident.u_brand_unlock" 
data-type="glide_list_unlock" data-ref="incident.u_brand" data-auto-close="false" 
data-placement="auto" style="margin-right: 5px;" list-read-only="false" 
data-original-title="Unlock Brand"><span class="icon icon-locked" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

I am trying to achieve this using the following code

```
driver.find_element_by_id("incident.u_brand_unlock").click()
```

Also tried this

```
driver.find_element_by_id("incident.u_brand_unlock").send_keys("\n")
```

The above codes are focusing on the button but it's not clicking and the text box is not unhiding to perform further operations.

Comment: Can you provide website link?

Comment: get the element's xpath and do `drive.find_element_by_xpath(path)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307040/how-can-make-style-display-none-element-visible-in-html-in-python-seleniu) . Had to remove the style attribute of the field I wanted to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ActionChains class in your code like below -

```
# Import
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

Button_Click = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'incident.u_brand_unlock')))
action.move_to_element(Button_Click).click().perform()
```

Comment: Already tried this, but forgot to mention in the question.
Spoiler alert : It doesn't work too. There is something I am missing. It is focusing and probably clicking too, but don't know why it isn't resembling the same thing we actually physcially click it.

Comment: Can you provide URL?

Comment: Sorry, not possible. It'll not open for you as there is an authentication step.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-default.btn-ref[id$='u_brand_unlock'][data-original-title='Unlock Brand']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-default btn-ref' and contains(@id, 'u_brand_unlock')][@data-original-title='Unlock Brand']/span"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```